Why can't crontab bash script access user .local directory?
My cronjob is running. But the bash script that is running does not properly invoke another program. Usually, including a full path resolves this issue. I've included a full path in my bash script but I still get this error.

Here are the contents of my bash script.
touch /home/william/Desktop/script.txt
pkill -9 spotdl
cd /home/william/Desktop/music
/home/william/.local/bin/spotdl download saved --user-auth

Manually running the script works. Why can't the cron instance access .local/bin/spotdl?
Thank you.

Check your files: the screenshot says /bin/spotdl is not found, whereas your script indicates /home/william/.local/bin/spotdl. The output of the screenshot must be from a different script.

@vanadium I think I figured it out. It looks like the output from pkill to the terminal was affecting the formatting of the next command in the script. I changed it to redirect the output to a text file instead and now it works. thanks
